# How to do error handling with subprocess pipes

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, subprocess

It seems that I can't access process.stdout twice. But I'm not sure how to get around it. I'm trying to catch any git errors resulting from my command, and capture any useful output.

If the output is erroneous or absent, I'd like to know about it so I don't end up attempting to modify a variable that doesn't exist or is meaningless.

However, it seems that by probing the output for error, I loose my ability to capture the meaningful output.

Is there a better way of doing this so I can satisfy both scenarios?

So far, I've just tried the two permutations. But when I check for validity first, I can't seem to access the output to do anything with it. However if I try to use it without validating, I loose my error handling.

```
def gitinfo(sha1, placeholder, repoDir = '/mnt/d/stash.projects/rea'):
    placeholders = {'hash':'%H', 'comment':'%s', 'time':'%cd', 'newline':'%n'}

    if placeholder not in placeholders:
        print('Error: function gitinfo is not programmed for paceholder: ' + placeholder)
        print('Please see source, or try \'hash\', \'comment\', \'time\', or \'newline\'.')
        return 'Good day.'

    format_option = '--format="' + str(placeholders[placeholder.lower()]) + '"'
    date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    date_option = '--date=format:\'' + date_format + '\''
    cmd = ['git', 'show', format_option, date_option, '-s', sha1]

    with subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=repoDir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as proc:

        if not proc.stdout.read():
            warn(proc.stderr.read())
            return 'Error retrieving ' + placeholder + ' in function gitinfo.'


        for line in proc.stdout:
            result = line.rstrip('\n')


    if placeholder.lower() == 'time':
        result = result.replace("'", "")

    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` and `stderr` aren't strings, they're streams. One way to think of them is like a water tank: the process is dumping water into the top, and you have a faucet at the bottom you can access. `stdout.read()` says "open the faucet and let it run until there's no more water in the tank" -- if you haven't placed a bucket under the faucet (assigning to a variable in this analogy), the water is gone, and opening the faucet from the empty tank again isn't going to bring it back.

If you need to access the same output from a stream multiple times, you have to store it in a variable and then reference that variable each time. In your case, you could do something like:

```
output = proc.stdout.read()
if not output:
    # your error handling here
for line in output.split("\n"):
    # do stuff with line here
```

Comment: Forgot to respond, thank you for your answer. I guess I knew it was acting like a stream.. but I didn't connect the dots. This is perfect.